# How to remove specific item from list?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to remove spam from the given choices on the menu, my `for` loop doesn't work.

```
menu = [
    ["egg", "bacon"],
    ["egg", "sausage", "bacon"],
    ["egg", "spam"],
    ["egg", "bacon", "spam"],
    ["egg", "bacon", "sausage", "spam"],
    ["spam", "bacon", "sausage", "spam"],
    ["spam", "sausage", "spam", "bacon", "spam", "tomato", 
    "spam"],
    ["spam", "egg", "spam", "spam", "bacon", "spam"],
]

for choice in menu:
    if "spam" in choice:
        remove("spam")
        print(choice)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: "remove" is not defined. Maybe you meant `choice.remove("spam")`?

Comment: See the [documention](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) of the mutable sequence `remove()` method.

Answer (score 7):

As stated by @h4z4, `remove` is not defined. Try

```
for choice in menu:
    if "spam" in choice:
        choice.remove("spam")
        print(choice)
```

However, `remove` only removes the first occurrence. To remove all occurrences, try:

```
for choice in menu:
    if "spam" in choice:
        choice = [item for item in choice if item != "spam"]
        print(choice)
```

Answer (score 5):

To remove all "spam" from sublists, use list-comprehension:

```py
menu = [
    ["egg", "bacon"],
    ["egg", "sausage", "bacon"],
    ["egg", "spam"],
    ["egg", "bacon", "spam"],
    ["egg", "bacon", "sausage", "spam"],
    ["spam", "bacon", "sausage", "spam"],
    ["spam", "sausage", "spam", "bacon", "spam", "tomato", "spam"],
    ["spam", "egg", "spam", "spam", "bacon", "spam"],
]

menu = [[val for val in subl if val != "spam"] for subl in menu]
print(menu)
```

Prints:

```py
[['egg', 'bacon'], 
 ['egg', 'sausage', 'bacon'], 
 ['egg'], 
 ['egg', 'bacon'], 
 ['egg', 'bacon', 'sausage'], 
 ['bacon', 'sausage'], 
 ['sausage', 'bacon', 'tomato'], 
 ['egg', 'bacon']]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As already pointed out `remove` is a method of `list` and  should be called as `choice.remove("spam")`
2. `remove` only removes the first occurrence of the element

Here is a way to do this with `remove` and `count`

**Code:**

```
menu = [
    ["egg", "bacon"],
    ["egg", "sausage", "bacon"],
    ["egg", "spam"],
    ["egg", "bacon", "spam"],
    ["egg", "bacon", "sausage", "spam"],
    ["spam", "bacon", "sausage", "spam"],
    ["spam", "sausage", "spam", "bacon", "spam", "tomato",
    "spam"],
    ["spam", "egg", "spam", "spam", "bacon", "spam"],
]

for choice in menu:
    c = choice.count('spam') # returns number of occurrences of 'spam' in choice
    while c: # to remove spam from choice c times
        choice.remove("spam")
        c-=1

print(*menu, sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
['egg', 'bacon']
['egg', 'sausage', 'bacon']
['egg']
['egg', 'bacon']
['egg', 'bacon', 'sausage']
['bacon', 'sausage']
['sausage', 'bacon', 'tomato']
['egg', 'bacon']
```

**But I would prefer list comprehension**